# Using Tails, having nothing to hide

Tags: tails

I just want to share my experience and ask some questions about this brilliant piece of software.

[skip this part and go to questions, I just cheering here]

Despite that even the official tutorial of ''how to install Tails'' wishes you ''good luck'' I just made it run with the first try in some 20 minutes, of which 15 was waiting to download and mount.

After the boot I made 2 clicks and the mobile broadband was connected. It is amazing how simple and elegant an operating system can be, and I'm baffling with windows since 1996

For once I manage to make the hard drive to stop, I'm doing huge room for paging for the windows since ever, it never stops doing its thing on the hard drive, today the HD just stopped while I keep useing the pc.

It even has pre installed Audacity, GIMP, Inkscape and Libreoffice... only missing Blender and the multimedia sector it's owned and ruled.

[questions]

1. Is there a simple way NOT to use the TOR network and the Tor browser with Tails? I want to log into accounts that I have with it, use google facebook etc... so using those tools makes me looking like a fool than anything else... I just want to use the OS, if anyone has problem with me, come and knock on my door.
2. Does the hardware wearing out faster by using Tails or it is better as I speculating?

Any other thoughts - suggestions are welcomed
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware doesn't wear out faster. Tails is pretty lightweight so I'd tend to say the contrary.

As to Tor, it is basically a Firefox modified version. You can use the options to disable the Tor network while still using the Tor browser. This way you will send a user agent that is very common and send very low amount of unique info which makes you harder to fingerprint. Tor probably has more to offer than just this. It probably tries to mitigate fingerprinting more than that. You can use Panopticlick (https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/) to test your browser for fingerprinting.

To disable Tor network on Tor browser use https://www.ghacks.net/2018/11/26/can-you-use-the-tor-browser-without-tor-connection/

I think that for security you should be using Qubes instead of Tails. Qubes works by creating virtual machines in a "dom0" machine. Dom0 is never connected to internet and is always hardware isolated from the Fedora(Linux) virtual machines you create. When you use Qubes you can just erase a virtual machine and all its memory in a few clicks. It makes your experience much more secure and you can download all apps which are compatible with Linux.

You may as well install DD-WRT on your router. Don't underestimate the security risks of having a router which has a default firmware from ISPs. They use it to send info and logs. Once you have DD-WRT installed, you can have a OpenVPN VPN outside of the US like NordVPN on the router with a kill switch which allows to browse anonymously on top of Tor network. The kill switch prevents any traffic to "pass" your router if it isn't routed through the VPN.

You can even set up a VPN in the computer and in the router on top of Tor network. That way you will have 2 VPNs on top of Tor. This can be used to mitigate attacks where ISPs and the end website collaborate to find you. Basically, if you use one VPN the ISP get your address and the end website gets it as well. They can thus identify you if they collaborate. With 2 VPNs they can't. This is due to the fact that the packets to the first VPN address is routed to the second VPN address at the VPN itself. With that configuration, you don't even need Tor. Unless you want to mitigate time based attacks. These are attacks based on timing to determine where the packet came from.

Another important thing to notice is that if you use closed source software (which you don't seem to do), you break the chain of security. You should always verify the SHA1 hash of the software you download to be sure they were not tempered with. Linux does that for you when you download software using the package manager.

You should be using different search engines than Google. Duckduckgo is a very good search engine which promises not to track you and does public campaigns to promote privacy. Their business plan is based on non-tracking publicity and technology. You can always fall back on Google if you need to.

Another thing is your email provider. You may want to set up secure email by hosting your own private email server using Postscript. You get a domain for low bucks or even for free and then use it to set up the email server pretty easily with open source software. That way you have secure email and can give away your new email address hosted on your name. You may need a dedicated machine to do that. You may as well use Protonmail as a fallback option.

The rest is up to you to be careful not to do stupid things like connecting to a social network with the VPN on. Anyway you seem to understand that already.

I already did all that and more. You may want to use bitcoins to pay for the VPN and use Tor to setup a Protonmail address that you then give to the VPN provider. That way, even the VPN doesn't know who you are. They only have your IP address. If they keep no logs as they pretend to, then you should not be traceable at all.

Comment: My thoughts on Qubes are so&so, it's a cheap way to have dedicated machines. The way I'm doing it for years is by buying cheap laptops without OS, ie buying a new one before the old is broken and use them for spasific tasks, some never connect etc, and ofcure never use antivirus, just a ''berserker'' machine and format it regularly. I believe that's the only right way, actually Isolated workstation. If you expect that they wont open the drawers of your desk because it is not polite you are a fool [don't mean you]. They only judge your polity and morality, theirs it's questionable because yeah.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simple way NOT to use the TOR network and the Tor browser with Tails?

Tails ships an untorified browser, called [the Unsafe Browser](https://tails.boum.org/doc/anonymous_internet/unsafe_browser/index.en.html).

Please note that this browser is sandboxed, so it's a bit tricky to share files with it.